# Wifi, Bluetooth & FM Radio not working in Lumia 720

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, nokia-lumia-720, radio

I've faced these problems:

- FM Radio app doesn't start,
- Bluetooth on/off button is disabled,
- When I want to enable Wifi, it ask to restart.

I've tried restarting my phone several times, and then tried to reset (both soft and hard). But the problem persisted.

Please help me what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you need a new phone.  It sounds like the radio isn't working.

Comment: You're right @Eric just returned from a Nokia Care, they said its a motherboard issue.. so we have to replace the motherboard :(